# javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception:org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

Hi i am getting this error while running JAX-RS WebService. i am creating JAX-Rs Web Service using Jersey. by following this link of http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Root cause

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getStatus(ContainerResponse.java:599)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(ContainerResponse.java:157)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused was that , i need to use same version jar for the jersey client , JAX-RS-WS. This removed my error . now i am running application successfully.